# Microsoft Graph, enumerate sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm learning Microsoft Graph API.  And am looking for assistance in using the  [SharePoint Enumerate items in a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) feature.

I've completed the [Microsoft learn tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/m365-msgraph-scenarios/) and want to take it a step further.

I had the idea of using a SharePoint list to update a website dynamically.  So, just show the list on the website with the items in a ul tag.

I think I will need to do the following:

1. Register the app in Azure with "Redirect URI" set to "Web".  And accounts in any organizational unit.
2. Use the tutorial template as my website template:  [template](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-retrieve-m365-data-with-msgraph-quickstart)
3. Find the site ID and the list ID.

That last one is where I am confused.  I've used the sharepoint graph to run some HTTP requests but those used a function called "GetByTitle('the list name')".  And in this case they are wanting the site and list ID.  Does this mean the site name, and list name, or the internal IDs of each?

I haven't found a good tutorial on using the SharePoint graph stuff.

If anyone has done this before, please share some tips with me.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, `GetByTitle` means getting items by SharePoint **list name**.

You can refer to this document to [work with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)